# Ubuntu: Convert OpenOffice Calc to Excel workbook using CLI

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, openoffice, openoffice-calc

I need to create an automated report in a spreadsheet format. Unfortunately, [There seems to be an easy way to create these reports using OpenOffice Calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356473/python-openoffice-programatically-manipulating-spreadsheets), but upper managements wants them in MS Excel format.

As these reports are to be created and emailed automatically, is there a nice, command-line way to convert between these file formats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a command-line way to convert between these file formats. But a macro must first be installed into OpenOffice. This macro will take a specified OpenOffice file name from
the command line and create a Microsoft Excel file (.xls) with the same name except for the file extension.

I have tested this with OpenOffice 3.2 on Windows, but I expect it to work on Ubuntu and with OpenOffice 1.1 or later.

The program to use on the command-line is `soffice`. On Windows it is not on the path and the absolute path must be used or the current directory be there.

Sample Ubuntu command-line (untested) that converts an OpenOffice spreadsheet 
file in `/home/mortense/temp9/test2.ods` to Excel format, `/home/mortense/temp9/test2.xls`:

```
"/usr/lib/openoffice/program/soffice" "macro:///Standard.doConvertToExcel.doConvertToExcel(/home/mortense/temp9/test2.ods)"
```

Sample Windows command-line used during testing that converts an OpenOffice spreadsheet file in `D:\temp9\test2.ods` to Excel format, `D:\temp9\test2.xls`:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice32\OpenOffice.org 3\program\soffice.exe" "macro:///Standard.doConvertToExcel.doConvertToExcel(D:/temp9/test2.ods)"
```

The macro is listed below. Here are the installation instructions:

1. Start OpenOffice [Calc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org_Calc).
2. Copy the code at the end of this answer to the clipboard.
   Create a macro:
   menu Tools/Macros/Organise Macros/OpenOffice.org Basic/.
   Then expand to "My Macros/Standard/" so that "Standard" is selected.
   Press button "New".
3. Right click on the tab in the lower left and select: Insert/BASIC Module.
   Right click on the created module, select "Rename" and type "doConvertToExcel".
   Click in the edit area (to set the focus there),
   select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)  and paste in the code. Close the window (e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>). That's it!

---

The code for the macro:

```
Sub doConvertToExcel( aFile )
   URL = ConvertToURL( aFile )

   ' Open the document.
   ' Just blindly assume that the document is of a type that OOo will
   '  correctly recognize and open -- without specifying an import filter.
   doc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL( URL, "_blank", 0, Array(_
            MakePropertyValue( "Hidden", True ),_
            ) )

   outFile = Left( aFile, Len( aFile ) - 4 ) + ".xls"

   outURL = ConvertToURL( outFile)

   ' List of filters: <http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=3549> and
   '                  <http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options>.
   '
   ' Save the document using a filter.
   doc.storeToURL( outURL, Array(_
                              MakePropertyValue( "FilterName", "MS Excel 97" ),_
                 )

   doc.close( True )
End Sub


Function MakePropertyValue( Optional cName As String, Optional uValue ) As com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
   Dim oPropertyValue As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
   If Not IsMissing( cName ) Then
      oPropertyValue.Name = cName
   EndIf
   If Not IsMissing( uValue ) Then
      oPropertyValue.Value = uValue
   EndIf
   MakePropertyValue() = oPropertyValue
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, that's a great, profound answer. Wish I could give you more than 1 upvote.